# Show recaptcha after 3 wrong attemps and process it in Django?

Tags: django, recaptcha

I am using `Class-based view` with Django: I want to show the captcha only after 3 times and process captcha only after it is shown. Till now, I can only show the captcha after one wrong attempt:

```
def post(self, request):
        response = captcha.submit(  
            request.POST.get('recaptcha_challenge_field'),  
            request.POST.get('recaptcha_response_field'),  
            '[[ MY PRIVATE KEY ]]',  
            request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'],)  

        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        state = "The username or password is incorrect."
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')
        else:
            #captcha = CaptchaField()
            public_key = settings.RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY
            script = displayhtml(public_key=public_key)
            return render_to_response('index.html', {'state':state, 'captcha':'captcha', 'script':script}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I want to show the captcha after three times and process it using response.is_valid. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably to store the number of attempts in a cookie, incrementing it on each failed attempt. Obviously this can be tampered with, which brings me to signed cookies:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_signed_cookie
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_signed_cookie

Essentially a signed cookie will raise an exception if the value has been tampered with.

You can also store the counter in the session, but I don't see any point in prematurely creating a session object when a cookie will do the trick.

Comment: What if the attacker doesn't send the cookie at all? Than you have no clue how many times the user has tried to log in.